# How can I improve this code so that there are no errors due to having multiple objects with the same name?

Tags: java, class, game-development

I want to make a text-based game, and I want to make it so the player chooses what ship they will pilot. Then after they pick a ship, whatever code I have after will reference the same object name as all other player-specific ships.

I have tried multiple google searches, but nothing seems to help. This is my first game that I will attempt to make, and no matter what I do I can't seem to rectify this issue

```
//Ignore all the ship.setupShip stuff that isnt causing me an issue

switch (shipSelector) {
            case 1:
                Frigate ship = new Frigate();
                System.out.println("Give your ship a name!");
                String shipNamer = keyboard.nextLine();
                ship.setupShip("Frigate", shipNamer);
                break;
            case 2:
                Shuttle ship = new Shuttle();
                System.out.println("Give your ship a name!");
                String shipNamer = keyboard.nextLine();
                ship.setupShip("Frigate", shipNamer);
                break;
            case 3:
                Cruiser ship = new Cruiser();
                System.out.println("Give your ship a name!");
                String shipNamer = keyboard.nextLine();
                ship.setupShip("Frigate", shipNamer);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
```

I want it to be so that I can have one name reference for all player ships since the basic part of the game won't need the specific types of ship.

The only error I get is:

```
Error:(49, 25) java: variable ship is already defined in method main(java.lang.String[])
```

Comment: Have a `Ship` parent class and then define `Ship ship;` above the switch and inside each case just do `ship = new Cruiser()` (Or `Frigate`/`Shuttle`)

Comment: That worked, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variable ship is already defined , like this:

```
switch (shipSelector) {
            case 1:
                Frigate ship1 = new Frigate();
                System.out.println("Give your ship a name!");
                String shipNamer = keyboard.nextLine();
                ship1.setupShip("Frigate", shipNamer);
                break;
            case 2:
                Shuttle ship2 = new Shuttle();
                System.out.println("Give your ship a name!");
                String shipNamer = keyboard.nextLine();
                ship2.setupShip("Frigate", shipNamer);
                break;
            case 3:
                Cruiser ship3 = new Cruiser();
                System.out.println("Give your ship a name!");
                String shipNamer = keyboard.nextLine();
                ship3.setupShip("Frigate", shipNamer);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use an `if else` block.

```
 if (shipSelector == 1) {
     Frigate ship = new Frigate();
     // do your other stuff here
 } else if (shipSelector == 2) {
     Shuttle ship = new Shuttle();
     // do your other stuff here
 } // put your other else if statements here
```

This option isn't optimal though, because you would have to do everything inside the `if else` statement, because the reference would be out of scope.

Another thing to try is to just have an abstract class `Ship`, and have `ShuttleShip` and your other ships extends that. Have one variable `Ship ship`, then make it equal a new specialized type.

```
Ship ship

switch(shipSelector) {
    case 1 :
        ship = new Frigate();
        System.out.println("Give your ship a name!");
        String shipNamer = keyboard.nextLine();
        ship.setupShip("Frigate", shipNamer);
        break;

    //etc.
}
```

Comment: Also, the definition of the `shipNamer` variable is the same in every branch, and it could be replaced with a single copy of that line before the `switch`, along with the `println` for the message.

Answer (score 0):

use { } wrap code can limit variable scope

```java
public static void main(String[] args){
 {
  int a = 1;
 }
 {
  int a = 1;
 }
}
```

```java
switch (shipSelector) {
            case 1: {
                Frigate ship = new Frigate();
                System.out.println("Give your ship a name!");
                String shipNamer = keyboard.nextLine();
                ship.setupShip("Frigate", shipNamer);
                break;
            }
            case 2: {
                Shuttle ship = new Shuttle();
                System.out.println("Give your ship a name!");
                String shipNamer = keyboard.nextLine();
                ship.setupShip("Frigate", shipNamer);
                break;
            }
            case 3: {
                Cruiser ship = new Cruiser();
                System.out.println("Give your ship a name!");
                String shipNamer = keyboard.nextLine();
                ship.setupShip("Frigate", shipNamer);
                break;
            }
            default:
                break;
}
```

Comment: It's always good to put some explanations with the code. Otherwise it's like writing code without putting any comments.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using an array(if you have fixed number of ships) or a arraylist(if you dont) ,so that you could write a loop allowing you to do the same action over all the objects in the array or arraylist.You could basically make a parent class called "Ship".and then child classes called "Frigate","Boat",etc.So that you can define the array as having "Ship" objects.

```
class Ship{
//whatever you methods are
}

class Frigate extends Ship {
//whatever you methods are 
}

class Boat extends Ship{
//whatever you methods are
}


public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

Ship[] ships = new Ship[5];//howmany ever you need
    ships[1] = new Frigate();
    ships[0] = new Boat();
}
}
```